Graphs with the same degree sequence and the same maximum eigenvalue
I'm looking for a suggestion please on how to prove the following:
Let $G, H$ be two graphs that satisfy the following: if there exists a matrix $S$
( with the property: $S1=1, S^t1=1$, $S$ is square and $1$ is the column matrix of ones only.) such that $AS=SB$, where $A, B$ are the adjacency matrices of $G, H$ respectively then $G, H$ have the same degree sequence and the maximum eigenvalue of $A, B$ coincide.
I have these results: (maybe they help)

I have found that if the matrix $S$ has the property ( $S1=1, S^t1=1$) then $S^t$ also has this property and if two matrices have the property then the product also has it.

Let $G, H$ be two graphs that satisfy the following: if there exists a matrix $S$ ( $S1=1, S^t1=1$) such that $AS=SB$, where $A, B$ are the adjacency matrices of $G, H$ respectively then $G, H$ have the same number of edges and vertices.
thank you


